# Default Pivot Point

Tags: origin

Is there a way to change the where the default pivot point for an added object is at? For example, can it be set so that when adding a cube the pivot point is at one of the bottom vertices, from the beginning without having to manually change it, instead of the current default at the object's center?

Comment: I guess you mean the origin of the object. Simple answer: no. Unless you are firm enough to change the source code to create your own build of Blender that has this feature.

Comment: Yes. Sorry if I got the terminology wrong.